# FileSystemException: Cannot open file while trying to write new file

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I'm trying to write file with custom name but getting error but if i used constant name it works just fine

here is my code

```
    Future downloadFile(String url, String name) async {
//creating path
final tempDir =
    (await AndroidExternalStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        DirType.downloadDirectory));
//filename genearted from 
customname = generated;
final file = File('$tempDir/myfolder/$customname');
  try {
    final response = await Dio().get(url,
        onReceiveProgress: (count, total) {
      setState(() {
        isDownloading = true;
        progress = ((count / total) * 100);
        if (progress == 100) {
          isDownloaded = true;
        }
      });
    },
        options:
            Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes, receiveTimeout: 0));

    var raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
    raf.writeByteSync(response.data);
    await raf.close();
  } catch (e) {
    log(e.toString());
  }
```

}

error log

```
[log] FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfolder/dunkin.zip' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

Comment: Error message would be helpful.

Comment: @BorisGrigorov i added it now

Comment: And does the application have storage permission?

Comment: @BorisGrigorov yes it has

Comment: Does `/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfolder` already exist?

Comment: as is said above everything works when using fixed names but when generating one it throw that error